# Bootstrap 3 Accordion not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

I have a Bootstrap 3 Collapsable List object but I can't make it work. I am missing something here?

[Here is the Bootply link](http://www.bootply.com/rTerMg1yWH)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug:

```
<div id="#ExprExp1" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true">
```

You left a # in the id. Try it without that. (in the tabpanels only).

The correct version http://www.bootply.com/QgceFfRi5T